# phone number search query

Tags: search, search-results, query, search-query, query-role

I am writing a query for phone numbers in search so when you input any part of the number it is returned by the search. I tried using this :

```
(MobilePhone:{subjectTerms} OR 
PhoneNumber: {subjectTerms} OR 
OfficeNumber:{subjectTerms} OR  
WorkPhone:{subjectTerms})
```

This only works when you put the whole number in, putting an `*` at the end of each `{subjectTerms}` only returns the number if you input what it starts with
Say if I had a number `123456789` and inputted anyone of the following `123`,`345`,`6789`,`4567`  and `123456789`etc it will return the people whose number matches the query

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Microsoft didn't have a solution on this problem so they made a ticket on it.

The only way I think of is to trim all numbers and duplicate those in another column. Then make a custom input field for search and put the * at the end before requesting a new search.